# What is the best practise to add 'adds' area in wordpress sidebar?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am currently developing a WP theme which I would like to release as a free theme. It should include an area at the very top of the sidebar in the theme which will be made of 4 spaces in which someone can come and advertise on the website.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/195/83818763.jpg

What are your suggestions about how to do this ? Do you have any online tutorial or something about adding this kind of functionality to the WP theme ? It should in the best case scenario be completly run through the admin backend (admin can set the image of the add, how long that image will remain in which add spot) etc.

I just need general guidelines, not the complete code for it :) Just direct me on how it should be done.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the Useful [Banner Manager plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/useful-banner-manager/installation/) to manage your ads. Once installed you'll get a widget that you can configure to your reference. There are also other options as well.